# HighCharts: Update the series name label dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been able to dynamically update the data on the charts using addPoint(), but am having trouble updating any other parts of the graph.

I'd like to update the series name.

[image]

I've tried setting the series.name directly in javascript, and I've tried calling series.setOptions() with the updated options (which includes the name). But the graph does not update, even if I call chart.redraw().

Comment: Are you trying to change the series name based on a point?  Or are you actually loading another series of datapoints that have a different series name?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do both - I'm mostly just wondering if I've missed something in the API that allows updating, or if this is the wrong way to do it, and I should be creating a new graph each time instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not optimal but after changing the series name, you could modify the legend directly by manipulating the SVG (assumes jQuery):

```
$($('.highcharts-legend-item tspan')[0]).text('SomeOtherLabel')
```

Or better yet, using the Highcharts API:

```
$(chart.legend.allItems[0].legendItem.element.childNodes).text('Hi Mom')
```

Comment: Yep seems like this is the way to do it. I don't think I will though, as it is not using the HighCharts javascript API, and I don't know how it will react to chart updates it doesn't know about. It seems they want you to recreate the chart when updating anything other than data points, as there is no javascript API to do it.

Comment: You suggest $(chart.legend.allItems[0].legendItem.element.childNodes).text('Hi Mom') to set the name in the legend. How can I read it?

Comment: @tic, you want to read what text is in the legend?  Wouldn't this be the series name?  So `someChart.series[series_index].name`?

Comment: No, the legend text is independent of the serie name. When you change the first, the second continues to be as it was before. So, how can I read the legend text after having changed it using your command?

Comment: @tic `$(chart.legend.allItems[0].legendItem.element.childNodes).text()`